# Search string in variable and return the matched string

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I need some help to match few strings stored in vector with address stored in a column of a data frame (data.table). My database is quite large around 1 million records and hence I prefer using data.table.

Below is dummy sample of the data and vector -

```
my <- data.frame(add=c("50, nutan nagar Mum41","50, nutan Mum88 Maha","77, amar nagar Blr79 Bang","54, veer build Chennai3242","amar 755 Blr 400018"))

vec1 <- c("Mum","Blr","Chennai")
```

I need to search for each of the strings in **vec1**  with each address in my variable **add**. If the variable finds any of the string from **vec1** in the address it should return the matched string in a new column **result**. Incase of multiple match, it should return the 1st matched value, i.e. Incase it finds "Mum" and "Blr" both in a single address it should return "Mum".

Based on the dummy data, expected result would be -

```
my$result <- c("Mum","Mum","Blr","Chennai","Blr")
```

I tried using grep / grepl but they give the error "argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

I tried using `str_match` but get TRUE / FALSE for each string in vector that is found in address but not the value itself.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(my$add, paste(vec1, collapse="|"))
#[1] "Mum"     "Mum"     "Blr"     "Chennai" "Blr"
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
regmatches(my$add, regexpr(paste(vec1, collapse="|"), my$add))
#[1] "Mum"     "Mum"     "Blr"     "Chennai" "Blr"
```

Comment: Much cleaner than my solution, wasn't aware of those functions. Thanks for introducing me ;)

Comment: @akrun, great!! Thank you!! you made it very simple.

Comment: @akrun, The solution works on the dummy data but is not working on the actual data. I have checked the variable types and converted them to characters, changed the class etc, but still it is not finding any text from the vector. In my actual data text is all in Korean characters, would that be an issue? How can we over come that. I have been trying since last night, but no luck. tried both methods. Please suggest!!

Comment: @user1412 Perhaps try `str_extract(my$add, paste0("\\b(", paste(vec1, collapse="|"), ")"))`  The characters could be an issue as you mentioned

Comment: @akrun, this too is not working :( it seems the Korean characters are creating issue. Korean characters are not getting identified properly it seems. Any way we can pass the encoding in this function? I have used gsub for replacement of korean characters with blank "", and it worked, Anyway we can use gsub but it should return the matched string, i.e. replace all non-matched text and keep only the matched one?

Comment: @akrun, I was trying the base code with updated paste0 code you provided, and getting this warning "In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 30206 items to be assigned to 448579 items of column 'RES_PSU_name' (recycled leaving remainder of 25695 items)." Could you please guide how to get rid of this?

Comment: @user1412  Can u check [this](https://rdrr.io/rforge/stringi/man/stri_enc_toutf8.html)

Comment: @akrun, Thanks a ton. By going thru couple of pages on this site, I figured out the code `stri_encode(str, from = NULL, to = NULL, to_raw = FALSE)` which did the trick. In my case I used `stri_encode(str, from = "EUC-KR", to = "UTF-8", to_raw = FALSE)` . Your original code without change in paste code worked. Thank you once again akrun :) !!

Comment: @user141  No problem, Glad to help you

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution with base R:

```
vec1[sapply(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(vec1, 
        function(x) {grepl(x,my$add)}))), function(y) {min(which(y))})]
```

returns:

```
[1] "Mum"     "Mum"     "Blr"     "Chennai" "Blr"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! I need to understand more on the apply family functions.

Comment: When I try to implement this code on my actual data of 1m records, with Korean text, I am getting the error"Error in which(y) : argument to 'which' is not logical".....what could be going wrong?